# custom routing in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, url-routing

I have multi store views in website,

```
The current URL for a category for the dutch store view would be;
      http://www.domain.ext/nl/category.html, 
      http://www.domain.ext/de/category.html etc
```

Now I want to add country code with store code. I mean to say, I am getting country code from Users Ip and want to extend it with store code. It will be look like

```
 If the country is set to NL the URL should now be;
       http://www.domain.ext/nl_nl/category.html
   If the storeview is Dutch (NL) but the country is Belgium (BE), the URL should become;
     http://www.domain.ext/nl_bel/category.html
```

I want this only in category page. I am trying to change in match function of standard.php, but I think its role starts from controller name, please help me how can I achieve it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to incorporate it into the URL like that?

I think you are going to fight a lot of Magento code to achieve it (product url, catalog url, indexing, getUrl functions and collections, rewrites).

I'm sure you have considered this and the many ways to do what you want but I think you are making work for yourself. Perhaps adding the country code as a URL query string ?c=bel or keeping it all internal to Magento by storing it in a session variable or a general function that you can call at any time eg getCustomCountryCode(). Using a cookie might be a possibility too.

If the URL is purely cosmetic then perhaps an `.htaccess` rewrite would suffice combined with some `rel='canonical' href="http://www.domain.ext/nl_bel/category.html"` on the category pages.

If you are determined to proceed then study the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`

Comment: Motive behind url change is I want to change url on the basis of country. I am using varnish, but I want to show product listing on the basis of country. So I have to make different url so that it will consider different url for different country.

Comment: Fair enough. I think you need to work through a lot of code starting at Mage_Catalog_Model_Url. You may want to look at [innoexts Zone Manager extension](Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front) or investigate setting up Magento with a different website or store for each country.